# I have multiple divs-items created dynamically, want effect on hover in specific item, How can i resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-4

I have multiple divs-items (class .card-img) created dynamically depending on DB records, I want the effect on hover. I put the following script, but on hover, all items make the effect, that's logic, but I want the effect ONLY in the div I'm hovering, not in all.

HTML:

```
 <div class="image card-img">
    <div class="card-overlay-info"></div>
    <img class="" src="{{asset($item->mainThumbnail())}}" alt="{{$item->title}}">
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$( ".card-img" ).mouseover(function() {
      $( ".card-overlay-info" ).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: `$( ".card-overlay-info", this ).fadeIn();`

Comment: Thanks adeneo !!  As you can see im a newbee with jquery. Thats ok! Thank you very much from Argentina.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to adeneo for answering my questions!!

This is the solution.. a simple argument this in script ;

$( ".card-overlay-info", this ).fadeIn();